# Are declarative sentences of "to be" should have time inside?

Tags: past-tense

Should declarative sentences of "to be" have some **expression of time** inside or it isn't necessary?

For example:

> I was a student. I was there. They were there. They were workers. She
>   was a cashier. She was crazy. They were happy. 
>   Are such sentences fine or in any case and necessarily I should add some expression of time such as **yesterday, one week ago, one hour ago** etc.?

Comment: No, you don't need any expression of time there.  Is there some reason you think one is needed?

Comment: By the way, it should be "Should they have...?" not "Are they should have...?"

Comment: That's what I told about sentences in present simple tense in verbal sentence, so since it's nominal sentence in simple tense I had doubt about that if it's the same as verbal.:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we are talking about creative writing, then you have a lot of freedom in how you express what you want to say.

In this case it's unclear when all this happened, but the sentences are themselves just fine. If the surrounding context tells us the time frame, there's no need to repeat it.  Example:

> It was years ago now, but I still remember like it was yesterday.
>
> I  was young. She was young. Hormones raged. Things happened. It's a miracle we didn't burn down the house.